# Retrieving data from database on click

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have a Raphael circle in my page and I want to retrieve some data from database when the circle is clicked.

My piece of code for this purpose is:

```
var circle = R.circle(x, y, 10).click(retrieveData());
```

The problem is, the function retrieveData is called when creating the circle and not when the circle is clicked.
How can I write a piece of code, which runs retrieveData only if circle is clicked and not on the creation of the object?

Comment: Hows about ajax? Proberbly you can get a more specific answer, if you post more source code.

Comment: actually I am using ajax to retrieve data in my function. But the problem is retrieve data is called at the very beginning of loading page rather than when I click the circle

Comment: Then read the second sentence of my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in events of Raphael (like all event driven paradigms) needs to be passed as a delegate (function pointer / function as variable name.)

Use the following code (note the absence of brackets after `retrieveData` function.)

```
var circle = R.circle(x, y, 10).click(retrieveData);
```